# leverage.plot() R - CAR package

Tags: r, diagnostic, leverage, partial-plot, car

I'm trying to complete a homework regarding added-variables and leverage plots using the `CAR` package.

In the documentation of the `leverage.plot(`) it says that "These functions display a generalization, due to Sall (1990), of added-variable plots to multiple-df terms in a linear model. When a term has just 1 df, the leverage plot is a rescaled version of the usual added-variable (partial-regression) plot."

I really don't understand what that means. 
Does anyone know what's the difference in the interpretation of a leverage compared to a partial-regression plot?